# Итоги выборов модераторов 2020

Tags: обсуждение, выборы, вехи

[Выборы  в модераторы сообщества Stack Overflow на русском за 2020 год завершились!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/4) От лица сообщества хочу выразить огромную благодарность всем участникам, которые  выдвинули свою кандидатуру на должность модератора сообщества, а также всем тем, кто принял участие в голосовании!

На основе выбора, сделанного сообществом, новыми модераторами стали:

[image: Barmaley] [image: Grundy]

<sub>Для получения более подробной информации об итогах выборов вы можете загрузить данные по [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/4) или [посмотреть отчет онлайн](https://www.opavote.com/results/6509808766156800/0).</sub>

Новые модераторы в самое ближайшее время получат заслуженный [«ромб»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). А пока, давайте вместе поблагодарим ребят за желание помочь сообществу в развитии!

Comment: Поздравляю с победой на выборах!

Comment: Подздравляю! Теперь очередь модераторских тревог будет под надёжной опекой)

Answer (score 24):

[image: Анимация выборов]

> ## Winners
>
> Winners are Barmaley and Grundy.

## Победители

Победители — [Barmaley](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5648) и [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999).

Answer (score 22):

Спасибо за поздравления и доверие.

По ходу голосования меня несколько раз посещала мысль о снятии своей кандидатуры в пользу [@eanmos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/185348/eanmos) — до сих пор не уверен, справлюсь ли.

Обещаю применять бан как можно реже (правда, одного сегодня уже временно заблокировал).

Answer (score 11):

## Поздравляю!

Ну что же, @Grundy, @Barmaley желаю удачи в модерации, надеюсь она будет такая же честная и справедливая как и у Сувитруфа с А К.

**P.S.** Не запутайтесь в админке, а то забаните кого-нибудь из порядочных людей ;) (это шутка, если что...)

Answer (score 9):

Поздравляю [Единственного профессионала™](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497370/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0/497455#comment590483_497455) и [@Barmaley](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5648/barmaley) с избиранием.

При этом искренне сожалею, что [@eanmos](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/185348/eanmos) не попал в модераторы, и очень надеюсь увидеть его кандидатуру в следующих выборах.