# С Новым 2021 Годом!

Tags: обсуждение, итоги-года

2020 был очень неоднозначный и, думаю, запомнился нам всем... Например, [обновленными шляпами, часть которых посвящена культурным особенностям наших международных сайтов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/12/15/hat-season-is-on-its-way-join-us-for-winter-bash-2020/).  Кроме того в этом году:

- Отметку в 100 тысяч баллов репутации достигли сразу три участника [@Igor](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10242/6), [@MaxU](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11053/6) и [@Qwertiy](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10924/6)
- [Мы провели очередные выборы модераторов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10833/6). Модераторами стали [@Barmaley](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5648/barmaley) и [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy)
- Расширили тематику сайта, официально включив [вопросы-соревнования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/code-golf)

#### Год в цифрах

| Таблицы 2020 | Stack Overflow на русском 2019 год | Stack Overflow на русском 2020 год |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Задано вопросов | 77 986 | 89 750 |
| Опубликовано ответов | 56 949 | 68 197 |
| Новых участников | 41 189 | 54 550 |

<sup>* Это абсолютные цифры, включая удаленные сообщения.</sup>

#### Несколько мыслей о будущем

- *Особое внимание отзывам участников*. В наступающем году, как и в уходящем, одной из центральных тем работы компании будет улучшения опыта участия на сайте. Чтобы понять как должен выглядеть сайт в будущем, мы планируем проводить еще больше [опросов](https://stackoverflow.blog/survey/), публичных обсуждений на Мете и [исследований](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/12/18/the-loop-a-community-health-indicator/). В наступающем году мы планируем сделать акцент на удовлетворенность сайтом участников с высокой репутацией (кураторов и модераторов).
- *Больше нововведений.* В этом году [компания закрыла серию E](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/28/ceo-quarterly-blog-post-3-series-e-funding/). Как результат, я лично ожидаю много нововведений и улучшений в движке, причем как совсем новых, так и реализацию существующих предложений, которые мы все давно ждем.
- *Улучшение правил сообщества*. Когда новый участник присоединяется к сообществу, он добавляет что–то свое в наше общее представление о том, как должен выглядеть Stack Overflow на русском. И это здорово! Я верю, что в будущем году наш сайт продолжит привлекать энтузиастов программирования, вместе с которыми мы выведем «культуру» сообщества на новый уровень. Ведь создать по–настоящему значимую базу знаний мы можем только вместе и для этого нам нужно сообщество, частью которого хочется быть.

С оптимизмом и нетерпением жду наступления Нового Года! =)

#### Stack Overflow — это мы! Давайте поздравим друг друга!

Присоединяйтесь к поздравлениям! Пожалуйста, поделитесь наиболее приятными позитивными событиями из жизни сообщества, которые запомнились именно вам. Если в уходящем году кто–то из участников сделал вашу жизнь лучше, пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь поздравить его, сказать ему «спасибо» в ответе к этому вопросу. Уверен, этот участник будет очень рад вашему вниманию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Большое спасибо всем участникам сообщества [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)! Поздравляю с наступающим Новым Годом и желаю всего наилучшего! Буду рад видеть всех в Новом Году!*

Comment: раньше в статистике был пять рядов, а теперь всего три. Куда они делись?

Comment: @Danis Спасибо за вопрос! В 2019 году были технические сложности с Google Analytics (те две строчки из GA). Поэтому я не добавлял данные по просмотрам, так как они были искажены. Я не уверен про этот год. После праздников постараюсь выяснить и добавить, если цифрам GA можно верить.

Comment: Что ж это вы у нас же теперь таблицы! ;)

Comment: *(кураторов и модераторов)* кто такие кураторы? Когда выборы кураторов? Какая им положена геометрическая фигура к имени?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я думаю это CM.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Кураторы — интересный термин, который не так давно появился на MSE. Технически, кураторы — это участники с репутацией более 2000. Я лично отношу к кураторам людей, которые активно участвуют в модерировании содержимого.

Comment: А да? Прикольно.

Comment: А можно про `выведем «культуру» сообщества на новый уровень` подробнее? Сказано красиво, но реально не понимаю, о чем это.

Comment: @Sevastopol' бескультурных будут банить без предварительного предупреждения!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я почему-то верю, что в нашем сообществе таковые отсутствуют. Или неужели есть, я например? Меня же забанили без предварительного предупреждения. Очевидно, это я бескультурный.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Никого не банить без разбора. _Никого_!

Comment: @Sevastopol' Культура сообщества, в моем понимании — это набор правил и практик коллективной работы. У нас прекрасное сообщество, хорошие правила, при этом всем нам определенно есть куда рости. Например, развитие подсообществ и их создание правил их взаимодействия между собой или расширение тематики сайта. Развитая культура сообщества, как и грамотный интерфейс программной системы, делает так, что сайт легко использовать правильно, вносить в сообщество что–то полезное, и сложно — неправильно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, чтобы дальше расти, предлагаю для начала думать более приземленно. Наверное, правила должны быть не хорошие, а правила должны работать, должны также работать и все написанные рекомендации. Мы все, кто не первый день уже в сообществе, знаем, какие у нас существуют проблемы внутри нашего сообщества. И их нужно решать. И их можно решить. А мы просто завуалируем их красивыми словами. Считаю, что необходимо начинать любой рост с решения насущных проблем. Ну а потом уже пытаться воплощать мечты в реальность. А иначе ничего не получится.

Comment: А я предлагаю не превращать поздравление с Новым Годом в перетирание правил, спор, демогогию и модробой! Для это есть другие места ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, только с добрыми намерениями. Всех с наступающим Новым годом! Хочу и желаю чтобы наше сообщество стало образцом, эталоном, чтобы на него ровнялись другие. Верю, или хочу верить, что когда-нибудь так и будет. Это вполне реальные цели. Главное двигаться в правильном направлении. Да услышит нас Дед Мороз! :) Всем здоровья, добра, любви и позитива в Новом году!

Comment: Дед Мороз уже готов,
Праздник мчит среди снегов.
Быстро набирает ход
Самый лучший Новый Год.

Все бубенчики звенят
И кружит гурьба ребят.
Пусть за дружеским столом
Грянет поздравлений гром.

Радость ждет за поворотом.
С новым счастьем! С Новым Годом!

Answer (score 10):

Друзья, товарищи, кто-угодно! Это был трудный год. Для многих он был очень тяжелым. В прочем любой год не однозначен. Я уверен, что многие из нас нашли в нём и положительные моменты. Надеюсь, что 2021 будет хороший, счастливый и удачный год. Всех с Новым Годом!

Поздравляю обычных участников с Новым Годом! Всех!Поздравляю модераторов ♦ с Новым Годом! Спасибо вам, вы нам очень помогаете! Поздравляю отвечающих с Новым Годом! Вы — движите наше сообщество! Поздравляю всех кто, достиг 100k в этом году — это вершины — а вас целых 3 человека среди которых один модератор — @Qwertiy ♦ (у него казалось бы работы хватает и по модерированию, какая тут скажешь репутация?)! Спасибо вам! Поздравляю не только наше сообщество, но и весь SE, частью которого мы являемся! Поздравляю Charcoal! У спамеров и троллей нет ничего святого — они продолжают даже на Новый Год. Но Charcoal даст им отпор! Поздравляю всех CM! Всех, кто движет сеть. Поздравляю всех!

*Всем счастья, позитива, любви, достатка, удачи, здоровья и хорошего настроения!*

## Поздравляю всех! Поздравляю всех с Новым Годом!

Answer (score 3):

***Присоединяюсь к  поздравлениям! С Новым годом! Всем здоровья и счастья!***

Хочется сказки на Новый год,

Пусть он исполнит  желанья!

И пусть защитит нас от бед и невзгод,

Не знала душа чтоб страданья!

Пусть волшебство случится в метель,

Всю боль унесёт пороша!

Пусть больше не будет у нас потерь,

Пусть будет только хорошее!

Пусть счастье ворвётся к каждому в дом,

Зальётся радостным смехом!

И зазвучит бубенцов серебром,

Отзываясь в сердцах наших эхом!

**И с наступающим Рождеством!**

На Рождество всегда снежок,

Несёт он радость людям.

Друзья, всё будет хорошо!

С ним  мир светлее будет!

Такая тишь и чистота…

Ничто их не нарушит.

Наш мир спасает красота,

Любовь  спасает душу.

Ладошку ты свою открой -

Увидишь волшебство:

За белых ангелов  игрой

Таится Рождество.

Звезда зажглась,  в ночи горит,

Путь освещает людям.

«Христос  родился!», – говорит,

Несите  весть о чуде.

И календарь теперь ведёт

С  Его рождения отсчёт,

И к году прибавляют слово

«…от Рождества Христова».

Гори, Восточная Звезда!

Зови зарю иную!

Заря Любви – мечта Христа  –

Надежду нам дарует!